# Find projection operator $P_{E}:H\rightarrow E \subset H$, H - Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

In Hilbert space $H=L_{2}(-\pi,\pi)$ we have three dimensional subspace $E:=\textrm{span}_{R}\{t,t^{2},sin(t):t\in[-\pi,\pi]\}$.

I have to find operator $P_{E}:H\rightarrow E \subset H$, its norm $||P_{E}||$ and distance $d(\sin(2t),E)$, note that $\sin(2t)\in H$. I would like to ask for tips on how to start a task.

Comment: Why is $\sin(2t)\in H$? ($1\notin H$.)

Comment: Could you solve the more general problem: given $a,b,c$ in a Hilbert space, find the orthogonal projection to their span?

Comment: Well, that is what I got for the exercise and it was wrote like that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes, $\sin(2t)$ is in $H$, but not in $E$, that's what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Use Gram -Schmidt Process to find an orthonormal set $\{f,g,h\}$ which spans $E$. This is the main step. Everything else will then follow from general theory: $P_E(F)=\langle F ,f \rangle f+\langle F ,g \rangle g+ \langle F ,h \rangle h$. $\|P_E\|=1$ (since any non-zero projection has norm $1$). The distance of any $F$ from $E$ is nothing but $\|F-P_E(F)\|$.

Comment: You mean $\|F-P_E(F)\|$.

Comment: Yes,thanks for the comment.

Comment: For calculating $P_E(F)=\langle F ,f \rangle f+\langle F ,g \rangle g+ \langle F ,h \rangle h$, what is my $F$? Should be a 'thing' to generate formula for such a projector?

Comment: @Michal You are asked to find the operator $P_E$ so you you have to write down $P_N(F)$ for any $F$. So $F$ is arbitrary